# How to pass object from webrole.cs to the controller of MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-roles, webrole

I am working on web role in the Azure cloud service. Basically my web role is an MVC application and how can I make the controller in MVC communicate with the webrole.cs class. For example, in the run() method in webrole.cs I have received a message and I want to pass it to the MVC controller, how can I do that?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: show your example code please

Comment: Same question asked 2 days ago by him: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433461/how-to-change-the-view-of-an-mvc-in-the-web-role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better use a azure service bus queue to do that. Send a message on Run, and take the message from queue in your mvc app.

Comment: Can I take the message from queue in the controller class? How can I do that?

Comment: yes you can. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I think I suppose to receive the message in webrole.cs and pass it to the controller. Is this possible?